# How to convert any nested json into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm currently working on a project that will be analyzing multiple data sources for information, other data sources are fine but I am having a lot of trouble with json and its sometimes deeply nested structure. I have tried to turn the json into a python dictionary, but with not much luck as it can start to struggle as it gets more complicated. For example with this sample json file:

```
{
  "Employees": [
    {
      "userId": "rirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Romin",
      "lastName": "Irani",
      "preferredFullName": "Romin Irani",
      "employeeCode": "E1",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-1234567",
      "emailAddress": "romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": "nirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Neil",
      "lastName": "Irani",
      "preferredFullName": "Neil Irani",
      "employeeCode": "E2",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-1111111",
      "emailAddress": "neilrirani@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

after converting to dictionary and doing `dict.keys()` only returns "Employees".
I then resorted to instead opt for a pandas dataframe and I could achieve what I wanted by calling `json_normalize(dict['Employees'], sep="_")` but my problem is that it must work for ALL jsons and looking at the data beforehand is not an option so my method of normalizing this way will not always work. Is there some way I could write some sort of function that would take in any json and convert it into a nice pandas dataframe? I have searched for about 2 weeks for answers bt with no luck regarding my specific problem. Thanks

Comment: This returns with a table, where a row is just one whole employee object. What im looking for is something where it could go through a json and format the dataframe in such a way that the keys would be column headings, so in this case those would be "userId, firstName.." etc

Comment: "``it must work for ALL jsons``" that's pretty broad. You do realize that this is valid JSON, too: ``[null, false, true, 1, 2.3, 1.2E+10, "", "\"", "abc", [], [0], [[],{}], ["", 4.5], {}, {"a": 1, "b": null, "c": {}, "d": {"d1": "", "d2": [false, {}, "d23"]}}]``

Comment: I guess to clarify, it should work for all jsons containing info about things so it can be presumed that there wont be jsons structured as above and general layout will be something like in the post or something generated from a request

Comment: "``jsons containing info about things``" well, the JSON I posted also contained information, could as well be information about "things". For us as humans it's easier to distinguish what data makes sense to us, but for a machine it's just data. That's why I said the "``it must work for ALL jsons``" requirement is too broad. JSON may be nestd indefinitely, so who is to tell, what data is relevant, at which level to start and where to stop normalizing? ...

Comment: ... If you have fixed "requirements", where you can always say "The top level is an object, the values are lists of objects, these values of these objects are plain strings" **then** you can easily write some logic. Otherwise it's pretty much impossible to cover all cases.

Comment: No way to get a useful dataframe that represents for `ALL jsons`, because a json can have nested jsons within it. You must be specific for json with certain data structure only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do that in the past (Flatten out a big nested json). This [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10) was really helpful. Would something like this work for you?

Note, like the others have stated, for this to work for EVERY json, is a tall task, I'm merely offering a way to get started if you have a wider range of json format objects. I'm assuming they will be relatively CLOSE to what you posted as an example with hopefully similarly structures.)

```
jsonStr = '''{
"Employees" : [
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Romin",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Neil",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
"employeeCode":"E2",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
}]
}'''
```

It flattens out the entire json into single rows, then you can put into a dataframe. In this case it creates 1 row with 18 columns. Then iterates through those columns, using the number values within those column names to reconstruct into multiple rows. If you had a different nested json, I'm thinking it theoretically should work, but you'll have to test it out.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import re

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out

jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
flat = flatten_json(jsonObj)



results = pd.DataFrame()
columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    row_idx = re.findall(r'\_(\d+)\_', item )[0]
    column = item.replace('_'+row_idx+'_', '_')
    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

print (results)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
  Employees_userId           ...              Employees_emailAddress
0           rirani           ...             romin.k.irani@gmail.com
1           nirani           ...                neilrirani@gmail.com

[2 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This does exactly what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

```
d={
"Employees" : [
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Romin",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Neil",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
"employeeCode":"E2",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
}]
}
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([x.values() for x in d["Employees"]],columns=d["Employees"][0].keys())
print(df)
```

Output

```
   userId jobTitleName firstName           ...            region  phoneNumber             emailAddress
0  rirani    Developer     Romin           ...                CA  408-1234567  romin.k.irani@gmail.com
1  nirani    Developer      Neil           ...                CA  408-1111111     neilrirani@gmail.com

[2 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is he was saying he isn't able to see the json structure beforehand. So he wouldn't know the key is `"Employees"`, or even if there are multiple keys at the first level and needs a robust way of dealing with the nested structure.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular JSON data given. My approach, which uses `pandas` package only, follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# json as python's dict object
jsn = {
  "Employees" : [
    {
    "userId":"rirani",
    "jobTitleName":"Developer",
    "firstName":"Romin",
    "lastName":"Irani",
    "preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
    "employeeCode":"E1",
    "region":"CA",
    "phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
    "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
    },
    {
    "userId":"nirani",
    "jobTitleName":"Developer",
    "firstName":"Neil",
    "lastName":"Irani",
    "preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
    "employeeCode":"E2",
    "region":"CA",
    "phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
    "emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
    }]
}

# get the main key, here 'Employees' with index '0'
emp = list(jsn.keys())[0]
# when you have several keys at this level, i.e. 'Employers' for example
# .. you need to handle all of them too (your task)

# get all the sub-keys of the main key[0] 
all_keys = jsn[emp][0].keys()

# build dataframe
result_df = pd.DataFrame()  # init a dataframe
for key in all_keys:
    col_vals = []
    for ea in jsn[emp]:
        col_vals.append(ea[key])
    # add a new column to the dataframe using sub-key as its header
    # it is possible that values here is a nested object(s)
    # .. such as dict, list, json
    result_df[key]=col_vals

print(result_df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
   userId lastName jobTitleName  phoneNumber             emailAddress employeeCode preferredFullName firstName region
0  rirani    Irani    Developer  408-1234567  romin.k.irani@gmail.com           E1       Romin Irani     Romin     CA
1  nirani    Irani    Developer  408-1111111     neilrirani@gmail.com           E2        Neil Irani      Neil     CA
```